# Toggle button navbar is slow to disappear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

When i want to close my navbar, the navbar is very slow to disappear. Here is the code

HTML

```
<!-- logo -->
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo g's shop">
    </div>
    <i class="ri-menu-line" id="menu-icon"></i>

<!-- nav -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill m4">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active .bg-white" aria-current="page" href="#">ALL ITEM</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SMARTPHONES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LAPTOPS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
    top: 65px;
    right: 30px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #f3efef;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-item {
    margin-top: -2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#menu-icon {
    display: block;
}

.nav.open {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS (JQuery)

```
$('#menu-icon').click(function() {
    $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Here's the video how slow it to disappear
https://youtube.com/shorts/9EHFJC8Q7Ac?feature=share

I expect faster disappear of all the menus right when i click it

Comment: I have already solved the problem with changing visibility: hidden; to display: none; Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved this problem by changing

```
.nav.open { visibility: hidden; }
```

with

```
.nav.open { display: none; }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you try this -
**Remove the transition property**

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
    top: 65px;
    right: 30px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #f3efef;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it still slow